# How to persist Firefox Bookmark pane setting?

Tags: linux, firefox, bookmarks

The latest Firefox has a bookmark button near the address bar. When the bookmark pane is showing and then Firefox shutdown, the bookmark state is lost. When Firefox restarts the bookmark pane is not visible.

The temporary bookmark view is a problem for my mother. She lost Windows because Microsoft bricked her PC with the Meltdown/Spectre updates. She is learning Linux and a new Browser but she is older and its a little harder for her.

Mozilla has a KB at [Use the Firefox sidebar to access bookmarks, history and social features](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-sidebar-access-bookmarks-history-social#firefox:win8:fx57), but it does not discuss how to make the changes permanent.

How do I ensure the Bookmarks pane setting is permanent?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is rewritten entirely to explain the sidebar behaviour in Firefox and using bookmarks in Firefox. Given that OP seems to believe that the only solution is to make sidebar persistent, this answer has changed the approach to offer documentation first and solution last.

**Sidebar behaviour in Firefox**

Firefox shows the sidebar when the user wants to quickly view Bookmarks or History. The following points describe the sidebar behaviour in Firefox.

- The sidebar is shown on the left (default) when visible.
- If the sidebar is already visible in a window, the sidebar will also appear in a new window (not applicable to a private window).
- If the sidebar is already visible in a window, then the window is closed and opened again, the sidebar will be visible.

The sidebar behaviour has been observed in Firefox 58 and older (notably Firefox 45, 37, 29) and found to behave consistently regardless of Firefox releases.

One exception is Firefox 29: When a tab is opened automatically and redirected to Mozilla page to notify Firefox version is outdated, the sidebar that supposed to remain open will be forcibly closed at startup. However, this is *not* observed in newer but outdated version i.e. Firefox 50.

Based on above, the sidebar in Firefox will usually remain visible after the sidebar is first opened and not closed by the user. The sidebar non-persistent behaviour is likely predefined and can not be modified by user configuration. No relevant setting in `about:config` from my finding.

**Using bookmarks in Firefox**

Mozilla has explained [how to access and organize bookmarks in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/bookmarks-firefox), which is found under "Learn the basics: Get Started". Notice that sidebar is *not* mentioned there. [Use the Firefox sidebar to access bookmarks...](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-sidebar-access-bookmarks-history-social) is explained anyway, but found under "Manage Preferences and Add-Ons".

The intended way to access bookmarks in Firefox is either from the menubar, dedicated buttons on the Toolbar, or Bookmarks Toolbar. Bookmarks are also accessible from sidebar however, the sidebar itself does not seem to be the intended way to persistently access bookmarks.

**Sidebar or other problem**

As hinted by documentation, using sidebar is actually less intuitive than already visible buttons on the toolbar. For Firefox users, I could identify three use cases:

1. To access bookmarks from somewhere that is *visible but temporary*, use either "Library" button, "Bookmarks Menu" button, or the hamburger menu (right-most) button on the **Toolbar**.
2. To access bookmarks from somewhere that is *visible but persistent*, use **Bookmarks Toolbar**. This is more legible than 1, since each item on Bookmarks Toolbar has favicons and text.
3. To access bookmarks from somewhere that is *accessible by keyboard*, use either access key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to open "Bookmark" menu in **menubar** or, keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to open "Bookmarks Panel" in **sidebar**.

Most end users would likely fall under use case 1 and 2, and some end users who prefer keyboard shorcuts would fall under use case 3. Power users may use the [Awesome bar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/awesome-bar-search-firefox-bookmarks-history-tabs) and even [Chrome URL](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Chrome_URLs) to access the bookmarks as preferred, depending on the work flow.

Above all, rather than trying to make the sidebar persistent (may not be feasible after all), try other ways to access bookmarks. The alternative solution is no longer suggested, since the setup was initially assumed to be done by OP and not OP's mother.

**TL;DR** Back to basics: Read [Help Topics for Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/firefox) before using the product. Do not decide from someone else perspective; Explain available choices and let the user decide what is best.

Comment: Thanks @clearkimura. The *Alternative Solution* will cause problems for her. She is retired and it is hard to teach her new tricks. Consider, asking her to click the bookmark button when the pane is missing is hard for her. She calls me and asks what to do. Lack of a page when the browser is open will be equally difficult for her.

Comment: @jww Given the limitations, I have no other solutions to offer. One thing for sure: Sidebar is not the most intuitive way to access bookmarks. Feel free to undo upvote if not useful.